# Pandas calculate manually for variance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, var

1.For a unique location, iterate through the dataset once to calculate the mean of the Kilometers_Driven.

2.For the same unique location, iterate through the dataset once more to calculate the variance of the Kilometers_Driven.

3.Repeat for all of the unique locations. Iteratively, calculate the mean and variance of the Kilometers_Driven for different location. Measure the time it takes.

4.Stop the timer. Print out the mean and variance of the Kilometers_Driven for each location as well as the time elapsed.

My codes:

```
#1
for l in list(df.Location.unique()): 
    col_mean = 0.0

    num_rows=0
    for row in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[row, 'Location'] == l:
              num_rows += 1
              col_mean += df.loc[row, "Kilometers_Driven"]
    col_mean = col_mean/num_rows

    print( 'Location: %s mean %.2f' % (l, col_mean) )

#2Calculating variance of "Kilometers_Driven" manually. how to add unique?

col_var = 0.0
for row in range(len(df)):
    col_var += (df.loc[row, "Kilometers_Driven"] - col_mean)**2
col_var /= len(df) - 1 
print(col_var)
```

But how to add unique Location for the second question??

Comment: Can you show some data?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/v9gmgxupkypn5dw/train-data.csv -so car_train_data.csv

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.read_csv('train-data.csv', header=0) 
data.groupby('Location')['Kilometers_Driven'].mean() 
data.groupby('Location')['Kilometers_Driven'].var()
```

Comment: 谢谢您，但是它是不是要叠戴计算（Iteratively），然后并不是简单groupby，二是需要列出那个unique location。